# WordPress on other parts of my site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress installation on my site, and I want to display WP posts on other parts of my site (that is outside the WP installation). How do I do that with PHP?

I tried to search this type of question on Stack Overflow, Google and WP official site but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sites explains how to do it.

http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages

http://www.webopius.com/content/139/using-the-wordpress-api-from-pages-outside-of-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Include the **wp-blog-header.php** from your WP installation. Then you have access to all WordPress functions and the database.